# Слетели картинки django-filer

Tags: python, изображения, django-cms, thumbnails

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перестали отображаться картинки django-filer, когда я перемещался по коммитам. Путь к картинке есть и он правильный, если перейти по ссылке, то картинка откроется, но на сайте и в админке они не отображаются (см. скриншот). Не работают вот именно картинки 'thumbnail' если просто в шаблоне вывести '{{image.url}}' все работает.
Уже откатывал проект, создавал новую бд, перезапускал проект, а результата ноль.

**Зависимости**

```
asgiref==3.6.0
awesto-djangocms-carousel==0.1.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
cssselect2==0.7.0
Django==3.2
django-admin-sortable==2.0.18
django-classy-tags==4.0.0
django-cms==3.11.3
django-filer==2.2.4
django-formtools==2.4
django-js-asset==2.0.0
django-mptt==0.14.0
django-polymorphic==3.1.0
django-ratelimit==4.0.0
django-sekizai==4.0.0
django-treebeard==4.4
djangocms-admin-style==3.2.3
djangocms-attributes-field==2.1.0
djangocms-file==3.0.0
djangocms-googlemap==2.0.0
djangocms-link==3.1.1
djangocms-picture==4.0.0
djangocms-snippet==3.1.0
djangocms-style==3.0.0
djangocms-text-ckeditor==5.1.2
djangocms-video==3.0.0
easy-thumbnails==2.8.5
html5lib==1.1
livereload==2.6.3
lxml==4.9.2
packaging==23.0
Pillow==9.4.0
psycopg2==2.9.5
pytz==2022.7.1
reportlab==3.6.12
six==1.16.0
sorl-thumbnail==12.9.0
soupsieve==2.4
sqlparse==0.4.3
svglib==1.5.1
tinycss2==1.2.1
tornado==6.2
transliterate==1.10.2
Unidecode==1.1.2
webencodings==0.5.1
```

Настройки media
settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

urls.py

```
 urlpatterns = [
        ...
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Кэш браузера чистили?

Comment: @Jazzis да, и с других браузеров тоже заходил